# Unity 3D - Rotate image over a static cylindrical image

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, apache-flex, three.js, unity-webgl

one customization part of my existing e-commerce website is created in adobe flex, where we are displaying effect of 360 degree rotation of mug (one can consider as cylinder) with all the customization (Add photo, text, layouts etc.) user has made in flex canvas , this was done very easily using paper vision 3D, now we are planning to replace flex with other technology but it seems impossible to achieve the same using HTML5, also we can't go with threejs or webGL due to its IE compatibility issues. While doing research I found Unity 3d which seems good for my purpose, any suggestion on this? I am very new to Unity and designing things, experienced person's opinion will save lots of time of mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I can say "very easily". I suppose your concern is about "putting that texture on the rotating mug, expecting that the texture rotates along with the mug".

If that's the case, you can have multiple choices, from creating a new texture (or merge more images into a texture), or just paste the texture on the mug, and let the "parent-child" system take care of the rotation.

(whatever the parent does, child objects will remain relatively in the same position).

In any way, for unity this should be a quite easy task :)

Comment: In current application, mug is steady, what rotate is the snapshot of the flex canvas, can we do the same in unity in javascript?

Comment: in simple way, we are having 1 image and other snapshot, I need to rotate the snapshot over the static image (kind of cylinder), which is having fix height, width , top and bottom radius.